# Anybody can help me with kernel memory of windows? About Paged Physical, Paged Virtual & Paged Limit

Tags: windows, memory, kernel

These days I've been dealing with a bug of my software which using lots of GDI objects, and I found when Paged Virtual is approximate with Paged Limit, my MFC app can't display what it should be. Then I solved this problem by changeing CreateCompatableBitmap function to CreateDIBSection.

But what I need to know is what's the relationship among Paged Physical, Paged Virtual & Paged Limit, Paged Limit seems not to be simply the sum of Paged Virtual and Physical, this has been really confusing.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/03/07/memory-management-understanding-pool-resources.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Windows Internals book

- Paged Physical - current physical (resident) size of paged pool (`Memory: Pool Paged Resident Bytes` performance counter)
- Paged Virtual - current total virtual size of paged pool (`Memory: Pool Paged Bytes` performance counter, `MmPagedPoolPage` (number of pages) kernel variable)
- Paged Limit - maximum (virtual) size of paged pool (`MmSizeOfPagedPoolInBytes` kernel variable)

[Pushing the Limits of Windows: Paged and Nonpaged Pool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx) by M. Russinovich

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I want, thanks, this will be very helpful! Cheers!